# mysqldump with some tables, not using --skip-table

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, unix

To dump a single database I can do:

```
mysqldump -u root files
```

To dump a single table I can do:

```
mysqldump -u root files path
```

How would I dump two tables combined? Something like:

```
mysqldump -u root files path&path_updated
```

Note that I have about 50 tables, only two of which need to be exported, so I don't want to do a `--skip-table` on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep adding table names

```
mysqldump -u root files path path_updated ...
```

Check the documentation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump databasename table1 table2` ([Reference](http://fosswire.com/post/2007/08/reference-making-backups-using-mysqldump/))